# When I reset the style of ::placeholder on a password input it turn into dots on Chrome & Safari browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I'm using `all: unset` on `<input type="password" placeholder="text of placeholder">` and the placeholder turn into dots.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="text of placeholder">
```

CSS:

```
::placeholder {
    all: unset;
}
```

The wrong, visual result of placeholder:

[image: Placeholder shown as bullets]

Is there any way to still use the `all: unset` and bring back the value of placeholder that will show up correctly?

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/jOaQPgZ/b4f692f748b2f625988f75c34f7375ce?editors=1100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `-webkit-text-security: initial;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security)

```css
.reset-input::placeholder {
  all: unset;
  -webkit-text-security: initial;
}
```

```html
<label>Reset Input</label>
<input class="reset-input" type="password" placeholder="placeholder text">

<br><br>

<label>UnReset Input</label>
<input type="password" placeholder="placeholder text">
```